# Retirar aspas quando fazer upload de csv

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Fiz a seguinte instrução para subir um csv para o banco de dados:

```
public void importarBaseBruta(File arquivo) {
    try {
        this.limparBaseBruta();
        this.con.conectar();
        this.stm = this.con.getStm();
        System.out.println("- IMPORTANDO BASE BRUTA");
        String path = arquivo.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
        String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' INTO TABLE base_bruta \n"
                + "CHARACTER SET 'latin1' \n" + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' \n" + " IGNORE 2 LINES;";
        this.stm.executeUpdate(query);
        this.con.fechar();
        System.out.println("- TERMINOU DE IMPORTAR A BASE BRUTA DIARIA");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO NO MOMENTO DE IMPORTAR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Mas quando o csv sube para o banco a coluna se desloca por causa de aspas que não são retiradas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coluna deslocada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como retirar ela.

Comment: Lendo cada linha do arquivo e fazendo um replace?

Comment: Eu fiz esse metodo para isso mas continua a mesma coisa https://pastebin.com/2dMDPWcu